# Combinatorics: Mathematic Recurrence

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

I got 
$\textbf{(a)}$ $f(n) = c_12^n + c_2(-10)^n$

and solved $\textbf{(b)}$ similarly.

However, (c)-(f) is not factorizable.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

c can be factored, just not in the integers.  Either complete the square or apply the quadratic formula.  d can be factored over the integers.  Do you know the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)?  That gives only $30$ factors to try. e and f yield to the rational root theorem as well-all polynomials that you see in class that are higher degree than quadratics will do so.

Answer (score 0):

c) (A - 1 + sqrt(6))(A - 1 - sqrt(6))

d) (A + 4)(A - 2)(A - 6)

e) (A + ​3)​(A -​ 1)​(A - ​1)

f) (A + 1)(A + 1)(A + 1)

Comment: For a clear homework problem, with no effort shown, we prefer to give a hint (or sometimes even close)